# Why is $.ajax always going to error callback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using jQuery version 3.4.1. The server side API is not throwing any error but the jQuery is callback is always going to error. What should be changed in my POST request? Thank you!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:58373/FileAddAPI/GetFileToken',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    data: $('#sToken').val(),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
        $("#log").append("Success</br>");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#log").append("Error " + xhr.responseText + "</br>");
    }
});

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult GetFileToken()
{
    string token = "testtoken";

    return Ok(token);
}
```

I see below in fiddler.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2XFNob3dDYXNlXEFwdGl0dWRlIEhvc3RlZFxTb2Z0d2FyZSBGYWN0b3J5XEZpbGVVcGxvYWRcRmlsZVVwbG9hZFxGaWxlVXBsb2FkQVBJXFN0YXJ0U2Vzc2lvbg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2019 17:53:15 GMT

410
testtoken
0
```

Comment: What does the Network tab in your dev tools tell you?

Comment: Please see my updated post with what I see in network tab.

Comment: a post request is adding data, not getting data for this there is GET-request??

Comment: @MicroLova its not true. You can use both for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jQuery is callback is always going to error.

Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

There are two simple workaround:

1.You could add `async: false` like below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:58373/FileAddAPI/GetFileToken',
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        data: $('#sToken').val(),
        ...
    });
```

2.Or if you do not send the cross domain request,you could add correct `content-type` and comment `crossDomain` like below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:58373/FileAddAPI/GetFileToken',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        //crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        data: $('#sToken').val(),
        ...
    });
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I tried all the things suggested here but they are no working in my case. I am not sure if it is because of the return type from the server side API. I have updated my original post with the response I see in fiddler. It was actually returning 3 lines in the data. It has 410, testtoken and then 0. I am not sure what those 410 and 0 mean here. Thank you.

Comment: The explanation of 410 is The target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent based on this link:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410  I suggest that you could  think about recent changes you made to your:1.API signatures
2.Folder restructure/reorganization of assets/resources,3.Routing changes,4.Rename of resources

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and add ajax option `contentType` solved the problem.
And you can specify return type which ajax expect.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json", <---- this option
    dataType: "text" <---- expected response type
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

contentType: ==> is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; 
       charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
          charset=UTF-8, which is the default.

dataType:

is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.